# How can a Terraform private provider obtain the kubeconfig of a GKE cluster

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Terraform script that creates a GKE cluster via `google_container_cluster`. I also have a private provider that I've developed, and I want the private provider to invoke `kubectl` on the new cluster. It needs the `kubeconfig` of the new cluster.

The manual method to get the `kubeconfig` is to invoke `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`. The private provider could shell this command. But I'd rather not disturb the local CLI state.

How can the cluster credentials of `google_container_cluster` get passed to my private provider?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, not sure if it is the best.

First, the Terraform passes the knowledge it has about the cluster:

```
# config
locals {
  project_id = "my_gcp_project_id"
  region = "us-east4"
}

# local client token
data "google_client_config" "client" {}

# the cluster
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-cluster-name"
  project  = local.project_id
  location = local.region
}

# send it into the private provider
data "my-provider-name_the_data_source" "my_provider_data_resource" {
  token = data.google_client_config.client.access_token
  server = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint}"
  cluster_path = "gke_${local.project_id}_${local.region}_${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.name}"
  ca = data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate
}
```

Then inside the private provider, it can invoke `kubectl` with:

```
func execKubectl(cluster_path string, server string, token string, caBase64 string, kubectlArgs ...string) ([]byte, error) {
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(".terraform", "gke")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name())

    caPem, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(caBase64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = tmpFile.Write(caPem)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = tmpFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    tmpPath, err := filepath.Abs(tmpFile.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    allArgs := append([]string{"--certificate-authority=" + tmpPath, "--server=" + server, "--cluster=" + cluster_path, "--token=" + token}, kubectlArgs...)
    cmd := exec.Command("kubectl", allArgs...)
    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

  return output, nil
}
```

Comment: Another way I found was to shell `gcloud` with `get-credentials`, with `KUBECONFIG` environment variable set to point to a temporary file; then `kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG}` works. This doesn't interfere with the default `.kube/config`, and it might be more reliable, but it is slower.

Comment: I moved the cluster settings to the `Provider()` to avoid repetition across data/resources. It works well. (They had to be `Optional: true`)